# BS Overlapping column content

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

In the code below, I am learning how to create 2 columns with the left column used as a scrollable navbar. I am still in stage zero here, so pardon the quality!

I encountered a problem with the setting of the `.sidebar` class to `"position:fixed"` in the left column. The problem is that the contents of the left column overlaps the contents of the right column when this positioning is used.

If I change the grid column size to say, `"col"` instead of `"col-sm-2"` the overlap issue is gone but I get a wide gap between the content in the left and that on the right.

I **must** use `"position:fixed"`, is there a way to prevent this overlapping?
Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/aq9Laaew/247932/

Comment: Do you want that both columns have the same height? Why you do you must use fixed position?

Comment: @mahan, i don't want the 2 columns to have the same height. I want the content not to overalp. I must use position:fixed because I am using a plug-in for scrolling (not shown) that implies this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `col-auto` class and a masking container to hold the width and height of the nav, please have a look at below working snippet, hope it helps :)

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
#REF0001>li>a {
  color: white;
}
.nav-mask,
#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 40vh;
}
#sidebar {
  background: #7386D5;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-auto">
      <ul id="sidebar" class="list-unstyled">
        <a href="#REF0001" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" onclick=" $('#PM0001').toggleClass('fa-minus-square fa-plus-square')">
          <i class="fas fa fa-plus-square" id="PM0001"></i>
          Parent-01
        </a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled" id="REF0001">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="nav-mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I  must use position:fixed.

Comment: please have a look at the above snippet with `fixed` property working fine :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please tell me what .nav-mask is doing?

Comment: it avoids the `col-1` with fixed nav to not overlap with `col-2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.